# How to get files/folders list out of our App container in the iCloud Drive by using the NSMetaDataQuery API?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I know every App in iCloud Drive can be thought as a container.

I want to know how to get files/folders list out of my App's container in the iCloud Drive by using the `NSMetadataQuery API`.

I have tried to use `NSMetadataQuery` to search it by setting the scope in the `NSMetadataQueryAccessibleUbiquitousExternalDocumentsScope`, but there is nothing response.

There is an example in [ShapeEdit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ShapeEdit/Listings/ShapeEdit_DocumentEditor_ShapeDocument_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016100-ShapeEdit_DocumentEditor_ShapeDocument_swift-DontLinkElementID_15) but there is still nothing there when I change the scope to `NSMetadataQueryAccessibleUbiquitousExternalDocumentsScope`.

I want to get all files or folders out of my app in the iCloud Drive like using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` but don't want to have User Interface interactive like `UIDocumentPickerViewController`.

Is `UIDocumentPickerViewController` the only way to access the iCloud Drive?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue. I am trying to access shared iCloud Drive documents from within the app. I added NSMetadataQueryAccessibleUbiquitousExternalDocumentsScope to the NSMetadataQuery searchScopes but it does not seem to see the the shared documents.